# Jquery .html() and .text() removing extra whitespace in IE7 & IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a piece of text stored in the html of the page as seen below.

```
<div id="contentTextOriginal" style="display: none;">
_Sales Area: 560 sq ft (52.02 m²)_ _Ancillary storage: 678 sq ft (62.99 m2)_ _Separate W.C./Cloakroom_ 

**Total: 1,238 sq ft (115.00 m2)**</div>
```

I am then using a link to place the HTML above in a input field for the user to edit using some jQuery

```
   var textToEdit = $('#contentTextOriginal').text();
   $('.editorTextBox').val(textToEdit);
```

I have tried both `$('#contentTextOriginal').html();` and `$('#contentTextOriginal').text();`  in IE7 all but a single space is stripped from the div.

So the text is then displayed as

"*Sales Area: 560 sq ft (52.02 m²)* _Ancillary storage: 678 sq ft (62.99 m2)_ *Separate W.C./Cloakroom* **Total: 1,238 sq ft (115.00 m2)**"

what do i need to do to make sure IE7 dosn't strip out all the white space?

I am using a markdown editor so the white space is important as it holds some of the formatting information.

Works in every other browser, just not IE7

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Edited to better explain the issue.

Comment: Why are you still testing in IE7? Isn't it time developers finally said adios to that horrible, horrible browser?

Comment: Yes I agree, but the people who pay the bill say otherwise, also its an issue in IE8 as well, so i have to fix it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to wescrow and Sohnee for pointing me in the right direction to why this is happening.

In IE7 & IE8 using the code

`$('#contentTextOriginal').html();` or `$('#contentTextOriginal').text();`

Will mean IE7 & IE8 stripping out any formatting, extra spaces / returns regardless of if the item is set correctly e.g. pre, white-space css.

The only way i could get round this was to use the function

```
document.getElementById('contentTextOriginal').innerText;
```

But this innerText is not supported in any other standard compliant browser FF/Chrome.

So I have hasd to put some condition JS in use inner text for IE8 and below and the jQuery for everything else.

Something like this will work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i_am_old_ie = false;
    </script>
    <!--[if LT IE  8]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            i_am_old_ie = true;
    </script>
    <![endif]-->

    if (i_am_old_ie) {
       textToEdit = document.getElementById('contentTextOriginal' + id).innerText;
    } else {
       textToEdit = $('#contentTextOriginal' + id).html();
    }
```

I hate using conditional scripts if anyone can think of another way I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that technically, browsers are only supposed to render a space when they encounter a run of white-space. So a series of spaces and tabs will render a single space in the content.

Normally to prevent this you would use:

```
white-space: pre;
```

To preserve all white space.

The problem is that even if you apply this CSS to the original content area, it doesn't preserve the white-space when you copy the content (although it does in the display if you show the hidden content). [Example on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/3p25C/).

Perhaps you could use more of a data-format to store the data in the DOM?

For example:

```
<div id="contentTextOriginal" style="display: none;">
{ 
    salesArea: "560 sq ft (52.02 m²)", 
    ancillaryStorage: "678 sq ft (62.99 m2)", 
    notes: "separate W.C./Cloakroom",
    total: "1,238 sq ft (115.00 m2)"
}</div>
```

You can then use this data to be as clever as you like... with some help from the [JSON website](http://www.json.org/js.html).

For example, you could create a form with the correct inputs (this is just an example, so there isn't much design, it just shows what is possible).

```
var originalContent = $("#contentTextOriginal").text();
var jsonData = eval('(' + originalContent + ')');

var dynamicForm = '';
for (var key in jsonData) {
  if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    dynamicForm += '<p><label>' + key  + '<br><input type="text" value="'  + jsonData[key] + '" name="'  + key  + '" size="40"></label></p>';
  }
}

$("#contentTextOriginal").after(dynamicForm);
```

[See this example in action](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/Qp9Pu/).

Comment: The issue is that the text comes from a markdown editor (user controlled) so the white space is required in order to get line formatting information. The example above was just some rublish that the user had typed. it looks though as IE7 just wont play ball.

Comment: I was seeing a similar issue in IE9 too, so it may be more of an issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this problem is known with IE7: http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2004/11/innerhtml_and_t.html I don't think there is a fix for it (at least for textareas). For pre tags (which suffered from the same bug) you could insert `<br />` tags. Maybe you could try that.